# Ideal coin toss experiment: Do previous trials affect the outcome of future trials?

Tags: statistics

For the question:

"If you flip a coin 7 times and you get 6 heads and 1 tail, what is the probability of the following flip is tails?"

Does the knowledge of the previous 7 trials affect the outcome of the 8th trial?

With my basic knowledge of statistics, I would say no. And that because each trial outcome is **physically** independent of the other trials, that the probability of getting heads or tails will always be 50/50.

But it is also true that over a 1000 trials, the number of heads and tails you have recorded should be close to 50/50. And as you go towards infinity, the results should be exactly 50/50.

So wouldn't that mean that the results of the 8th trial in the above question would have a **greater** than 50% chance of being tails? Because eventually the record of the results must reach equilibrium at 50% heads and 50% tails?

Thanks!

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system)

Comment: *Because eventually the record of the results must reach equilibrium at 50% heads and 50% tails?* It ain't so.

Comment: P = 0.5 . There is not a driven force that tries to restore the ratio. Continue performing more trials and, just by chance, the ratio will tend to 0.5.

Comment: This question may be more of MathSE question, but just to say I  have a friend who avoids the winning  numbers in the previous week's national lottery, he is convinced they can't come up twice in a row.

Comment: Are you assuming a perfect coin? If so, the 8th trail will not be affected by whatever happened before. Probably that's the answer you (or your book/teacher) is looking for. However, you don't know if your coin is perfect, and most likely it isn't (at least in the real world). Hence you would expect a higher chance of seeing heads again in the 8th tail.

Comment: @pfnuesel My friends and I used to use a related strategy to stay safe when doing something risky.  We would make a point of talking about the possible but unlikely bad outcomes  (e.g. falling off a roof) at length under the hope that this would make it "to ironic to happen".  It seems to have worked, though of course, we were probably just fortunate.

Comment: @user1420303 What do you mean by chance? Why will the ratio tend to 0.5? And if we know that, doesn't that intrinsically make a trial more or less likely to be heads or tails depending on the previous trials?

Comment: The definition of a fair (i.e. ideal) coin dictates that it would not depend upon previous throws. P(H) = P(T) = 0.5.

Comment: @Miniucnchew, I think it is better to write it in an answer. I am going to do that.

Comment: the standard answer is not but you can play with words and say that the probability of the next outcome(s) depends on the statistics of the previous trials. ( edit : already said )

Comment: at the 8th trial, you may wonder if the coin is fair or if it is a serie.

Comment: @igael:  If you "may wonder" this at the 8th trial (in the sense of assigning a positive probability to the event "not fair"), then you *must* wonder this (in exactly the same sense) even before the first trial.

Comment: @WillO: implicitely in the case of the lack of knowledge of what happens before. But you're true. We are cutting hairs in 2x2 ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physics. It is a frequent asked question on [math.SE].

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the probability that a single toss returns heads.  If you start off believing that $p$ has some density function $f$ on the unit interval, you can easily use Bayes's rule to update your density function to

$$g(p)={7(1-p)p^6 f(p)\over\int_0^17(1-x)x^6 f(x)dx}$$

For example, if you start off believing that $p$ is uniformly distributed, you get

$$g(p)=56(1-p)p^6$$
which gives a probability of heads on the next toss of
$$\int_0^1pg(p)=7/9$$

Comment: *"if you start off believing that pp is uniformly distributed"* distributed in what sense? What is the meaning of the function $f$?

Comment: This is true, but misleading to OP. They have a much simpler confusion, i.e. the gambler's fallacy, which is already hard enough when the prior is a delta function at $1/2$.

Comment: Also, this answer is mixing up objective probabilities (the long-run average of events, which is what the OP is asking for) and subjective probabilities (your priors and posteriors), and makes it sound like the latter can influence the former. The objective probability of heads on the next toss doesn't change.

Comment: @knzhou:   We can let the coin be objectively drawn from an ensemble of coins whose weightings are uniformly distributed and the same math applies.  (I'm sure you know this but am mentioning it for the sake of others.)  Of course then we're reduced to the question of how sure you are about that distribution is.....

Comment: @knzhou:  But more fundamentally:  The OP is entertaining the possibility that the coin is not fair.  That means his prior is *not* a delta function at 1/2, so we can discard that case.  I agree that the OP might not have thought all this through,  but given that the problem *assumes* a non-bulleted prior, I think any answer must take that non-bulleted assumption as given.

Comment: @WillO I don't think this is what the OP was thinking. They say that if you've had more heads than tails, tails might be _more_ likely on the next trial to "make up" for the lack of tails. This is precisely the opposite of what real Bayesian reasoning gives, as you know.

Answer (score 0):

> Why will the ratio tend to 0.5?

If you make a list of every possible sequence of N coin tosses (where N is even), and then you count the number of heads and tails in each sequence, you'll find that more of them have exactly N/2 heads and N/2 tails than any other ratio.

```
Note 1:  You can actually try this at home.
```

You'll also find that ratios that are *close* to N/2 heads and N/2 tails vastly outnumber ratios where the numbers of heads and tails are substantially different.

```
Note 2:  For extra credit, Google "Binomial Distribution."
```

If you actually toss a coin N times, you basically are choosing one of the possible sequences at random.  You are more likely to choose one of the "balanced" or "nearly balanced" sequences simply because there are more of them to choose from.

That is why the ratio tends to 0.5.

> And if we know that, doesn't that intrinsically make a trial more or less likely to be heads or tails depending on the previous trials?

Nope.  Let's say you've tossed your coin N times (that is, you've randomly chosen one of the $2^n$ possible sequences of length N.

OK, make a list of every possible sequence of length N+1.  You will find exactly two entries in that list that begin with the same length-N sequence that you've already chosen.  One of them ends with an H and the other ends with a T.

```
Note 3:  You can try this at home too.
```

When you toss the coin for the N+1st time, you are randomly choosing between those two possible sequences:  a 50/50 chance.